# Fazer insert/update com valores de outras tabelas

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho esta bd. Quero fazer um insert/update a tabela faltas_licao. Mas não tenho nenhum id, apenas os números e nomes. Como faço para fazer um insert/update a relacionar com outra tabela?

```
Dim sql As String = "insert into Faltas_Licao values ()"
```

Comment: você quer fazer um update ou insert?

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta pelo fato de ser update no titulo e no contexto você usar insert, mas vamos lá, você pode usar o select para fazer isso da seguinte forma.

```
Declare @disciplinas table
(
    Id_Disciplina int,
    Nome varchar(50),
    Descricao varchar(200),
    Aluno_Id int
)

insert into @disciplinas values(1,'sql','mod 1',1)

Declare @Alunos table
(
    Id_Aluno int,
    Descricao varchar(200),
    Id_Turma int,
    Nome varchar(50)
    -- ......
)
insert into @Alunos values(1,'.....',1, 'joão')
Declare @Licao table
(
    Id_Turma int,
    Id_Disciplina int,
    Licao int
    -- ......
)
insert into @Licao values(1,1,1)
Declare @Turma table
(
    Id_Turma int,
    Nome varchar(50)
    -- ......
)
insert into @Turma values(1,'teste 1')

Declare @Faltas_Licao table
(
    Id_Turma int,
    Id_Disciplina int,
    Licao int,
    Tipo varchar(50),
    Descricao varchar(200),
    Aluno_Id int
)

insert into @Faltas_Licao 

select t.Id_Turma, l.Id_Disciplina,l.Licao, 'falta', 'falta por atraso', a.Id_Aluno
from @Turma t
join @Licao l
on l.Id_Turma = t.Id_Turma
join @disciplinas d
on d.Id_Disciplina = l.Id_Disciplina
join @Alunos a
on a.Id_Aluno = d.Aluno_Id
-- where ...?? 


--ou update
update fl 
set fl.Id_Turma = t.Id_Turma, 
fl.Id_Disciplina = l.Id_Disciplina,
fl.Licao = l.Licao,
fl.Tipo = 'falta',
fl.Descricao = 'outro motivo', 
fl.Aluno_Id = a.Id_Aluno
from @Faltas_Licao fl
join @Turma t
on fl.Id_Turma = t.Id_Turma
join @Licao l
on l.Id_Turma = t.Id_Turma
join @disciplinas d
on d.Id_Disciplina = l.Id_Disciplina
join @Alunos a
on a.Id_Aluno = d.Aluno_Id
-- where ...?? 

select * from @Faltas_Licao
```

Comment: Tem razão. Como no programa vou ter de fazer os dois, foi por causa disso que me baralhei a escrever a pergunta. 

Tendo em conta que já tenho valores nas outras tabelas, como faço para fazer o insert na tabela 'faltas_licao' apenas sabendo o numero da lição o nome da disciplina, e o nome da turma?

Comment: ou isto é o insert que tenho de fazer?
`
insert into @Faltas_Licao 

select t.Id_Turma, l.Id_Disciplina,l.Licao, 'falta', 'falta por atraso', a.Id_Aluno
from @Turma t
join @Licao l
on l.Id_Turma = t.Id_Turma
join @disciplinas d
on d.Id_Disciplina = l.Id_Disciplina
join @Alunos a
on a.Id_Aluno = d.Aluno_Id
-- where ...?? 
`
mais as declarações em cima?

Comment: Sim, você vai ter que monta uma consulta. `Select * from suas_tabelas` para obter os valores para fazer o insert na tabela que você quer, como são mais de uma tabela vai precisa usar o JOIN para uni-las. Como você falou ... **como faço para fazer o insert na tabela 'faltas_licao' apenas sabendo o numero da lição o nome da disciplina, e o nome da turma** user esses campos no where o na união das tabelas.